# how can I make a schedule(start, stop) for EC2 via API

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I want to make a schedule and apply it to EC2 instances. How can I make schedule by using java sdk? for example, my schedule should contain policy that start instance at 7 am and stop instance at 6 pm.

Answer (score 2):

This can be very easily achieved by using a lambda function triggered by a cron pattern. Make sure to assign a role with permissions to start/stop your instances to the lambda function.

1. Create a lambda function and then select `CloudWatch Events` under the section `Add Triggers`;

[image]

2. Configure your desired pattern, you will need something like `cron(0 7,18 * * *)`;

[image]

References:
 1. [Using AWS Lambda with Scheduled Events](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-scheduled-events.html)
 2. [Tutorial: Starting an EC2 Instance (Java SDK)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/how-to-ec2.html)